# What is the minimal set of essential libraries for Face Detection in OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, dependencies

While trying to use OpenCV for face detection on Windows, I need to pull in almost all the libraries (2d, 3d, ml, gui etc.).  Otherwise my program wouldn't run.  I am not really sure why I need any GUI for something as algorithmic as object detection.  What is the minimal set of libraries required and is there a special way to build OpenCV such that there aren't that many dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You need opencv_core to get base objects like cv::Mat, opencv_imgproc to use thresholds, histograms and other image pre-processing, and opencv_highgui for reading, writing and displaying images, and using video streams from cameras and video files. That's all I can tell you without knowing how to run openCV on Windows, and not knowing which version of openCV You are using. As far as I know there is no way of building only some parts of openCV.

Generally from my experience You only need to add libraries associated to headers which You are using. So, if you have problems with tracking them try to avoid using `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` and try a bit harder way of `#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"` etc.

Comment: Do you have some example of reading/writing images to the disk without using the API in highgui library?  I want to use the rest of the OpenCV API like core, 2d, etc. but I dont want a dependency on highgui library as all I want from this library is the image file-handling for which it drags in the whole Win32 API world.

Comment: I do not understand what You have wrote. If You want to avoid win32 API then highgui is excellent choice, because it gives single API for any system on which You can run OpenCV. I've only used binary fstreams to save some OpenCV data without using their native mechanisms, so I don't think there is anything to show.

Comment: What I am saying is that I don't want any GUI in my app and using highgui for image read/write unnecessarily pulls in several Win32 dependences that I don't need in my app.

Comment: As Matt M. said above, You can use some other library to save images, or use fstreams to save the objects to files, but that seems to be very unoptimal way. [Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1136/building-the-video-io-part-only/) is an answer showing how to disable some sublibraries of OpenCV. After a short glance on current verision of OpenCV highgui header, it looks like there is no way to include only the part responsible for reading and writing images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build OpenCV without certain library features. OpenCV uses [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), which requires a little learning if you don't know it already, but you can uncheck OpenCV components you don't need in the CMake build configuration.

You can get away without using highgui in your app if you can read images with some other library (but not sure if you can build OpenCV without it).

Also - you will need to `#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"` for support of Haar cascade classifiers (as of OpenCV 2.3.1).